# Possible typo in Krizhevsky et al paper on CNN?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, conv-neural-network

In the famous Krizhevsky-Sutskever-Hinton [paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf) on training a CNN to classify images and achieve (at the time) record performance on the ILSVRC competition set, I'm trying to understand their network architecture.
[image: Architecture of KSH's CNN]

The caption says that the 2nd layer contains 253,440 neurons, but I can't see how they get that number. The layer size appears to be 2x48x55x55=290,400. Is this a typo or am I missing something? The other layers work out, e.g. the next layer is 186,624 neurons = 2*128*27*27.

Comment: Did you try to contact and ask directly to the authors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733636/the-number-of-neurons-in-alexnet.  It's almost certainly a typo.  (They probably inadvertently calculated the layer size as `2x48x48x55`.)  Even brilliant people make mistakes. :)